# Grid not covering all the screen in UWP app

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

Why my grid is not covering all the screen and how can i fix it? On the designer looks like it should be covering all the width of the screen, but actually leaves a big space on the rigth.

```
 <Grid Background="GreenYellow">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


</Grid>
```

This code is only a snip, but even with childs the space its there on different sizes.

**Edit 1:**

> Acoording to Luis C. answer i get the same result big empty space to the left:

[image: still a blank space to the left]

I found a strange workaround to achieve what i want:

```
 <Grid  Background="Yellow">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="This is a very large text that only is used to strech all the childrens to the infinite. This is a very large text that only is used to strech all the childrens to the infinite. This is a very large text that only is used to strech all the childrens to the infinite. This is a very large text that only is used to strech all the childrens to the infinite. This is a very large text that only is used to strech all the childrens to the infinite" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <Button Content="Black" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>


    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Black" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Black" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

</Grid>
```

The result is:

[image: Result with workaround]

Still its a very strange way to workaround the problem.

**Full Code**

As you see, im using a SplitView on a GridView that loads Pages(like the one with the mentioned problem) on a Frame inside the SplitViewContent. Other Pages with TextBlock as childrens cover the whole screen as i want. The code for the SplitView is:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject.ViewModels.HomePage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyProject.ViewModels"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RelativePanel>
        <Button Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" FontSize="36" Click="HamburgerButton_Click" Background="LightGray"/>
        <!--<Button Name="BackButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE72B;" FontSize="36" Visibility="Visible" Background="LightGray"/>-->
        <CommandBar Name="Bar" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" ClosedDisplayMode="Compact" RelativePanel.RightOf="HamburgerButton" Visibility="Visible" Background="LightGray" IsOpen="False" IsSticky="True" >
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <TextBlock Name="BarTitle" Text="Title" FontSize="24" Margin="24,8,0,12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

            </CommandBar.Content>
        </CommandBar>
    </RelativePanel>
    <SplitView Name="MySplitView" 
               Grid.Row="1" 
               DisplayMode="Overlay" 
               OpenPaneLength="200" 
               CompactPaneLength="56" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox SelectionMode="Single" 
                     Name="IconsListBox" 
                     SelectionChanged="IconsListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBoxItem Name="SymbolsListBoxItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="x" Width="36" Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"> </Image>
                        <TextBlock x:Uid="Symbols" Text="[Symbols]"  FontSize="24" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>                 
            </ListBox>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content >
            <Frame Name="FrameHolder"></Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
    <Frame Name="HomePageFrame" >
        <!-- Frame not used by now-->
    </Frame>

</Grid>
```

The full code page snippet is(with more children) and the result the same, big blank empty space to the right:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyProject.ViewModels.SymbolsPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyProject.ViewModels"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:data="using:MyProject.Models"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="myListViewStyle">
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="CanReorderItems" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="36"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="140"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,4,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />

        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="SymbolViewer">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Fonts/etc"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>


    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GradBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset=".5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ItemGradBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">

        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset=".5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Page.Resources>



<!-- Spinners  -->


<StackPanel Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0">
    <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource GradBackground}" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

            <ListView Name="Uno" ItemsSource="{x:Bind UnoItems}" Style="{StaticResource myListViewStyle}" BorderBrush="White" 
                          BorderThickness="2" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Uno_ItemClick">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Thingy">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Symbol}" FontFamily="/Fonts/etc"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

            <!-- Not user interactive-->
            <TextBlock Text="0" Width="36" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>

            <!-- Spinner 2 -->
            <ListView Name="Dos" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DosItems}" Style="{StaticResource myListViewStyle}"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Dos_ItemClick">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Thingy">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Symbol}" ></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

            <ListView Name="Tres" ItemsSource="{x:Bind TresItems}" Style="{StaticResource myListViewStyle}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Thingy">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Symbol}" ></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
            <ListView Name="Cuatro" ItemsSource="{x:Bind TresItems}" Style="{StaticResource myListViewStyle}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Thingy">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Symbol}" ></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

            <ListView Name="Cinco" ItemsSource="{x:Bind DosItems}" Style="{StaticResource myListViewStyle}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Thingy">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Symbol}" ></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>

            <ListView Name="Seiss" ItemsSource="{x:Bind TresItems}" Style="{StaticResource myListViewStyle}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Thingy">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Symbol}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>


</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Is it inside of another container?

Comment: Yes, its inside a Page. Not sure if container but its his parent

Comment: Try setting the Margin on the Grid to zero.

Comment: please put all the xaml( the page and the grid) to find the problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the "RowDefinition" without height and change the "Auto" Rows to "*".

Something like this:

```
<Grid Background="GreenYellow">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Black" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Black" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Black" Background="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Luis C. Please check my edit because i get the same results with your answer.